# extract all values for specific key from space delimited text file

Tags: regex, awk, grep

have a text file in the format

```
1=23 2=44 15=17:31:37.640 5=abc 15=17:31:37.641 4=23 15=17:31:37.643 15=17:31:37.643
```

I need a regex to extract all the values for key 15 for a multiline text file

output should be

```
17:31:37.640 17:31:37.641 17:31:37.643 17:31:37.643
```

Sorry, I should have stated that the values I'm trying to extract are timestamps in the form `17:31:37.643`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GNU grep to extract the substrings.

```
grep -Po '\b15=\K\S+' | tr '\n' ' '
```

- `-P` option interprets the pattern as a Perl regular expression.
- `-o` option shows only the matching part that matches the pattern.
- `\K` throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.

Output

```
17:31:37.640 17:31:37.641 17:31:37.643 17:31:37.643
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to only capture the first instance of the key / value pair in a given line though.

Comment: ah yes, but each match is printed on a separate line, is there a way to print all matches on a single line?

Comment: @shaz Just pipe your output through *xargs*.

Comment: That would produce incorrect output if `115=whatever`, for example, was present in the input and it will add a trailing blank char to the output.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree, could use a word boundary. Suggest a better way than use `tr` or `xargs printf`?

Comment: I think grep has an option for whole words that might work in this case too for avoiding false matches. If `\b` means `blank` then don't use it or it won't match the start of the line. No, I think if you use grep you're stuck with post-processing it in some way to convert the newlines to spaces.

Comment: No `\b` is a zero-width assertion that asserts at both the start of the string or between a word char and not a word char.

Comment: Ah, that should be fine then. Thanks for clarifying. The grep option I thought might work is `-w`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/15=\([^ ]*\)/\1/g;s/[0-9]\+[^ ]\+ //g' input.file
```

---

*Gave that answer before OP added the expected output, it will work too, but adds a new line after every value:*

If you have GNU grep, you can use a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that comes with perl compatible regex mode:

```
grep -oP '(?<=15=)[^ ]*' <<< '1=23 2=44 15=xyz 5=abc 15=yyy 4=23 15=omnet 15=that'
```

Output:

```
xyz
yyy
omnet
that
```

Comment: You are welcome. Like that lookbehinds too :) .. Gave an additional sed example that produces your expected output (without the line breaks)

Comment: How would you modify that if the values for the specified key were timestamps and not simple character strings?

Comment: it does not need to get modified for that

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'=' -v RS=' ' -v ORS=' ' '$1==15 { print $2 }' file
xyz yyy omnet that
```

Set the Input and Output Record Separator to space and Input Field Separator to `=`. Test the condition of column1 to be `15`. If that is true, print the second column.

As suggested by Ed Morton in the comments, this would leave a trailing blank char or even an absent newline. If thats a concern, you can use the following using GNU `awk` for multi-char `RS`.

```
gawk -F'=' -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '$1==15{ printf "%s%s", (c++?OFS:""), $2 } END{print ""}' file
```